# Docker attach command removing my container from list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, docker-compose, pry

Requirement is to use gem 'pry' with docker. I want to debug rails application. so i have added "stdin_open: true and tty: true" in my docker-compose.yml. Here is my docker-compose.yml web section is looks like:

```
web:
image: ruby:version
stdin_open: true
tty: true
volumes:
  - .:/24tru:cached
  - log:/24tru/htdocs-rails/log
  - tmp:/24tru/htdocs-rails/tmp
  - node_modules:/24tru/htdocs-rails/node_modules
  - bundler:/bundler
  - ruby:/usr/local/lib/ruby
  - ./httpd.conf:/etc/httpd/conf.d/24tru.conf
  - ./docker/base/php.conf:/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf
  - ./docker/server.crt:/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/24tru_dev.crt
  - ./docker/base/php.ini:/etc/php.ini
  - .configuration.sample.inc.php:/24tru/includes/configuration.inc.php
  - ~/.ssh:/home/dev/.ssh:ro
  - ~/.aws:/home/dev/.aws:ro
  - ./raw_video_upload:/var/mnt/raw_video_upload
ports:
  - 8080:8080
  - 80:80
  - 443:443
extra_hosts:
  - "ul.fv.localhost:192.168.65.2"
command: 'sudo apachectl -DFOREGROUND'
```

So i ran my container using command

```
docker-compose up -d
```

then, to check container id i ran

```
docker ps
```

i got out put

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7eRt.png
```

After that i tried to attach container(first one in the list) to use binding.pry output

```
docker attach container_id(bf39b3bcc211)
```

but it exited without any output and when i ran again "docker ps"
my container "24tru-app_web_1" is no longer in the list. see output

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruYBM.png
```

Please help me to use pry gem with docker

Comment: Instead of using "attach" maybe try "exec"?

Comment: @SteveBoyd no that didn't work.

Comment: Please show the entire command which you are using to exec.

Comment: @SteveBoyd i am using command:
docker exec container_id

Comment: That command alone won't do much good, you probably want something like this:
```docker exec -it <<container_id>> /bin/bash```

Comment: @SteveBoyd. the command you mentioned is for login into the container,  that is working. But i need the screen where server is running.